# Easier way to call a function with many parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

for example I got the following function in Javascript/Typescript (real one is a generated REST Api from OpenApiGenerator)

```
doStuffAsGet(a: string, b: string; c: string; d: string, e: string, ...)
```

Now I would only call the function with parameter c, the rest should be undefined.
Is there a way not to have to write many many undefined only to supply this one parameter?

Comment: Change your function signature to accept an option object.

Comment: You can wrap your function with another one that accepts only single parameter: `const doSimpleStauff = (c: string) => doStuffAsGet(undefined, undefined, c, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional parameters - use the name suffix `?` to make a parameter optional:

```
function doStuffAsGet(a: string, b: string, c: string, d?: string, e?: string) {

}

doStuffAsGet('a', 'b', 'c');
doStuffAsGet('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
doStuffAsGet('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
```

You can make a, b, and c required, but have the rest optional (you choose which you must have by using the `?` as appropriate).

You can also have defaults - specify a default value using the `=` operator:

```
function doStuffAsGet(a: string, b: string, c: string, d: string = '', e: string = '') {

}

doStuffAsGet('a', 'b', 'c');
doStuffAsGet('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
doStuffAsGet('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
```

And rest parameters, where the name prefix `...` is used. This collects all subsequent arguments into an array.

```
function doStuffAsGet(a: string, ...others: string[]) {

}

doStuffAsGet('a', 'b', 'c');
doStuffAsGet('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
doStuffAsGet('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
doStuffAsGet('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
```

Note in the above example, `a` is needed, so you can't call the function with zero arguments. Again, you choose what is needed and what isn't.

A combinations of these may get you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Rest parameters, deconstruction... All in the following example :

Things to know :

- `void 0` equals `undefined`
- `...` is the spread operator
- `[,,c]` is called deconstruction

```js
function doStuffAsGet(...args) {
  const [, , c] = args;

  console.log(args[2], c);
}

// Way to call #1
doStuffAsGet('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');

// Way to call #2
doStuffAsGet(void 0, void 0, 'c', void 0, void 0, void 0);

// Way to call #3
doStuffAsGet(void 0, void 0, 'c');

// Way to call #4
const args = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
  args.push(void 0);
}

doStuffAsGet(...args, 'c');

// Way to call #5
doStuffAsGet(...[0, 1].map(() => void 0), 'c');
```

---

---

As @Nikhil Aggarwal said in the comment you can also turn the args into an object which will be way easier to use and maintain like :

```js
function doStuffAsGet({
  a,
  b,
  c,
  d,
}) {
  console.log(c);
}

function doStuffAsGetAlternative(obj) {
  console.log(obj.c);
}

// Way to call #1
doStuffAsGet({
  c: 'hi',
});

// Way to call #1
doStuffAsGet({
  a: 'salut',
  c: 'hi',
  d: 'buenos dias',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try and use the rest and spread operators, I don't know the goal of this function so I can't help you there, but check this out

https://javascript.info/rest-parameters-spread-operator